# 'start-storybook' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: reactjs, npm, storybook

```
PS C:..project\src\features> npm run storybook

> sfe-template-20@0.1.0 storybook
> start-storybook -p 6006

'start-storybook' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Installed storybook but can't seem to make it run. I tried npm install, will not help.

npm: '8.1.0',
node: '16.13.0'
"react": "^17.0.1",

Comment: why not `npm run start-storybook`?  Regardless this is a `$PATH` issue. Using the full path to start-storybook is likely the easiest way to solve it.

Comment: this is not the path i use, path is changed due anonimity

Comment: well sure, but the path you use isn't working: if you're calling `my\path\start-storybook` and it says 'not recognised as command` you're not pointing at the executable

Comment: fixed it, node version had to be changed. not a path issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the node version had to be downgraded to 14.15.0. After that I did `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install`. Since I am using Windows, before changing node version, I had to install NVM for Windows, then install the right node version and change it in CMD (have to run as Administrator).

Comment: A major part of this fix is that the `node_modules` was reinstalled. A node downgrade may not be needed for most people, just clearing node_modules and reinstalling with the storybook packages.

Answer (score 5):

After running `npx sb init`

then run `npx sb@next automigrate`

Then lastly modify your scripts in package.json to:

`"storybook": "sb dev",`

`"build-storybook": "sb build"`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, all you have to do is change the version of all the storybook packages in package.jscon to the same version (preferably to the lowest version that any package has, for example all packages have version 7.2.04 and one has 6.5.16 then you change it to 6.5.16) then you remove node_modules and package-lock.json and then npm or yarn and it should be fine

Comment: Worked for me.

"@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.21",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",

Comment: This worked for me also as it installed a mix of v6 and v7 packages, so manually downgrading the v7 ones back to the same v6 version got everything working!

Comment: In my case I have an Angular project, but once I downgraded all versions to 6.5.16 it gives me error with react saying that it's not installed. But after the install there is no change

Answer (score 1):

Storybook may not have actually been loaded into your `node_modules` folder.

After installing storybook using a utility like `npx storybook@latest`, you then must actually load the storybook code into your `node_modules` folder. Do this with `npm i` if using npm, or running `yarn` if using yarn.